# Sumprod-if formula in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like this (a1,a2 and a3 are string)

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 0.1 | 500 |
| a2 | 0.2 | 300 |
| a3 | 0.11 | 200 |
| a2 | 0.13 | 700 |
| a1 | 0.3 | 300 |

I trying to build a new dataframe as a sumprod of B and C based on A values. The output should look something like:

| A_values | sumprodif |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | 140 |
| a2 | 151 |
| a3 | 22 |

My initial solution was to use an if formula, create a list and edit the new dataframe from there. However, my if formula does not seem to be working:

```
if df['A']=="a1":
    sumprodif_a1 = (df['B']*df['C']).sum()  
return sumproduif_a1
```

Which returns the following error

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I would love to use this as a chance to learn a better way to do this kind of operation.

Thank you!

Comment: The problem here is `if df['A']=="a1":`.  That works on the entire column at once.  It returns a vector (true, false, false, false, true), so there is no "single value" for the `if` statement to check.  You always have to think about whether you are working with a single value, a whole row, an entire column, or the entire table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) on the multiplied values:

```
out = df['B'].mul(df['C']).groupby(df['A']).sum().reset_index(name='sumprodif')

# or
# out = (df.assign(sumprodif=df['B'].mul(df['C']))
#          .groupby('A', as_index=False)['sumprodif'].sum()
#        )
```

Output:

```
    A  sumprodif
0  a1      140.0
1  a2      151.0
2  a3       22.0
```